# Is there a group $G$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\simeq (\mathbb{Q},+)$?

Tags: group-theory

My guess is that no such $G$ exists. All I know is that if $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is abelian, then $G$ is two-step nilpotent. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is locally cyclic (*i.e.* every f.g. subgroup is cyclic), can we say more about $G$ in this case? Must it polycyclic-by-finite?

What I can show is that there is no group whose automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}$.

> **Proposition.** There is no group $G$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

*Proof.* If $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic (because it is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$, and is therefore isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$), and this implies that $G$ is actually abelian. Let's write $G$ additively: then the inversion map $\sigma(x):=-x$ is an automorphism $\sigma:G\rightarrow G$ with $\sigma^2=1$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ has no elements of order $2$, the only possibility is $\sigma=1$, which means $2x=0$ for all $x\in G$. Therefore $G=V$ is actually an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space, infinite-dimensional since $G$ has to have infinite cardinality. But then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)=\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is not abelian (*e.g.* it contains finite symmetric groups). QED

---

Now I want to show the same result with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{Q}$.

If $G$ is a group with $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\simeq \mathbb{Q}$, then perhaps by mimicking some Galois theory, we can find a group $H$ so that $\mathrm{Aut}(H)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$? This would contradict the above proposition.

(Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I did a lot of searching and found nothing before deciding to post.)

---

Here is another attempt along the same lines.

> **Proposition.** There is no *finitely-generated* group $G$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

*Proof.* Same technique as above. If $G$ is finitely-generated, then $G/Z(G)\simeq \mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is a finitely-generated subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is locally cyclic, it follows that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, so $G$ is abelian and we're done. QED

Comment: The argument actually works for any nontrivial locally cyclic group (=subquotient of $\mathbf{Q}$) with no element of order 2.